# Draw canvas line on image not effect entire area using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have small html5 project that need to draw line on image using canvas. Below is a sample code that I found in forum.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; }
    #canvas{
        border:1px solid red;
    }
</style>
<script>
$(function(){
    var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
    var imageOpacity=1;
    var canvasPos = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    var dragging = false;
    var img=new Image();
    img.onload=start;
    img.src="http://res.publicdomainfiles.com/pdf_view/84/13939501819528.png";

    function start(){
        canvas.width=canvas.width=img.width;
        canvas.height=img.height;
        ctx.strokeStyle="green";
        ctx.lineWidth=3;

        $("#canvas").mousedown(function(e){handleMouseDown(e);});
        $("#canvas").mousemove(function(e){handleMouseMove(e);});
        $("#canvas").mouseup(function(e){handleMouseUp(e);});
        $("#canvas").mouseout(function(e){handleMouseUp(e);});

        // redraw the image
        drawTheImage(img,imageOpacity);
    }

    function drawTheImage(img,opacity){
        ctx.globalAlpha=opacity;
        ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
        ctx.globalAlpha=1.00;
    }

    function handleMouseDown(e){
      var pos = getCursorPosition(e);           
      dragging = true;
      ctx.strokeStyle = 'green';
      ctx.lineCap = 'round';
      ctx.lineJoin = 'round';
      ctx.lineWidth = 3;
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.moveTo(pos.x, pos.y);
    }

    function handleMouseUp(e){
       dragging = false;
    }

    function handleMouseMove(e){
      var pos, i;
      if (!dragging) {
          return;
      }
      pos = getCursorPosition(e);
      ctx.lineTo(pos.x, pos.y);
      ctx.stroke();
    }

    function getCursorPosition(e) {
      return {
          x: e.clientX - canvasPos.left,
          y: e.clientY - canvasPos.top
      };
    }

}); 
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

I have problem once draw line at bottom area of image. Line not draw for big image, Script work fine just for small image ,(example big image in above code) Any advise or guidance would be greatly appreciated, Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've changed the `getCursorPosition` to use [getBoundingClientRect()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect)

```js
$(function() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  var imageOpacity = 1;
  var canvasPos = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  var dragging = false;
  var img = new Image();
  img.onload = start;
  img.src = "http://res.publicdomainfiles.com/pdf_view/84/13939501819528.png";

  function start() {
    canvas.width = canvas.width = img.width;
    canvas.height = img.height;
    ctx.strokeStyle = "green";
    ctx.lineWidth = 3;

    $("#canvas").mousedown(function(e) {
      handleMouseDown(e);
    });
    $("#canvas").mousemove(function(e) {
      handleMouseMove(e);
    });
    $("#canvas").mouseup(function(e) {
      handleMouseUp(e);
    });
    $("#canvas").mouseout(function(e) {
      handleMouseUp(e);
    });

    // redraw the image
    drawTheImage(img, imageOpacity);
  }

  function drawTheImage(img, opacity) {
    ctx.globalAlpha = opacity;
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    ctx.globalAlpha = 1.0;
  }

  function handleMouseDown(e) {
    var pos = getCursorPosition(e);
    dragging = true;
    ctx.strokeStyle = "green";
    ctx.lineCap = "round";
    ctx.lineJoin = "round";
    ctx.lineWidth = 3;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(pos.x, pos.y);
  }

  function handleMouseUp(e) {
    dragging = false;
  }

  function handleMouseMove(e) {
    var pos, i;
    if (!dragging) {
      return;
    }
    pos = getCursorPosition(e);
    ctx.lineTo(pos.x, pos.y);
    ctx.stroke();
  }

  function getCursorPosition(evt) {
  var ClientRect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    return {
    x: Math.round(evt.clientX - ClientRect.left),
    y: Math.round(evt.clientY - ClientRect.top)
  }
  }
});
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; }
    #canvas{
        border:1px solid red;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```